# Load protecting a multi database mariadb cluster with HAProxy

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant, mariadb, haproxy

I have a setup were multiple databases (one per tenant) live within the same mariadb server (or cluster). The goal is to protect mariadb from to many connections but also from to many connections to each database. Basically throttle each tenant at the database level without affecting others.

Example: The tenant1 database is being hit hard and limited at a total of 10 connections. Other connections are queued. At the same time tenant2 can continue working as normal because it has not hit any limit and is therefore not affected by the queue.

I know HAProxy is great if you have one database being hit from multiple applications as you can have connections queued in HAProxy instead of hitting a hard limit in the database and having to deal with that in the application.

So the question, can HAProxy be used as a front for multiple databases within the same cluster (potentially with their own database credentials) and allow throttling connections per database. Or would you need multiple HAProxy servers for that (one per tenant)?

Comment: Does the Account Resource Limits feature in MySQL/MariaDB work for you? - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html

Comment: @tan-hong-tat I have looked at account resource limits, but believe that will just raise an error if the limit is hit and the error needs to be handled in software. I quite like the feature of them just being queued.

Comment: @rick-james will do. But havent been able to find any information on queueing and multi-schema.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set up separate VMs, each with a MySQL instance.  Then throttle access via CGroups.  With this approach, HAProxy (etc) is not relevant unless you have some replication also.

CGroups has the feature that each VM can get "at least a certain percentage" of various resources (CPU, net, I/O).  When the system is too busy, that percentage becomes a max.  When otherwise idle, users can use more than their share.

You have set the `VARIABLE` `max_user_connections`?